# Average score jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am working with jupyter notebook.

I have some data with scores from three different courses.

I have to calculate the average score, and english will have

30% weight of the average score, math 50% and literature 20%.

How can I find the average score and append it to a column.

[image: The data I have]

Comment: _append it to a column_ Column of what? What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to import the data.

```
df=pd.read_csv("Your_data.csv")
```

then you can add a new column of averages using apply function.

```
df['Average']=df[['english','maths','literature']].apply(lambda e,m,l: e*.3+m*.5+l*.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following once you read the file with `read_csv` function :

```
df['average'] = df['english'] * 0.3 + df['maths'] * 0.5 + df['literature'] * 0.2
```